# Stop unwanted flash animation on UICollectionViewCell after calling view.layoutIfNeeded

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've a chat screen built with UICollectionView and there's a bottom container view that contains the textview and some buttons

When I update the bottom constraint of the container view and call layoutIfNeeded it results into a weird "flashing" animation on the cells.

On willDisplayCell I've done this

```swift
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But it looks like it's affecting nothing.

I use Typist to handle the keyboard and that's how I animate my constraints

```swift
        keyboard
            .toolbar(scrollView: mainView.chatCollectionView)
            .on(event: .willChangeFrame) { [weak self] options in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                guard self.mainView.sendMessageTextView.isFirstResponder else { return }
                let height = options.endFrame.height
                self.mainView.bottomContainerViewBottomConstraint.constant = -max(0, height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                    self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { _ in })
            }
            .on(event: .willHide) { [weak self] options in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.mainView.bottomContainerViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                    self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { _ in })
            }
            .start()
```

Also reverting to default keyboard listeners via NotificationCenter did nothing so I don't suspect the library is the problem.

As you can see on this video the cells are kind of "flashing" is there anyway to stop that flashing from happening ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjZ62df5i2w

Comment: Can you try to put the modification of the constraint inside the animate block for both events, to be honest with you my eyes didn't catch the flashing but the movement is not smooth, that's because of the updates was written outside the animated block